# How to change the name of the EC2 instances created by an AutoScaling Group?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I am new to CDK and I don't manage to find a way to change the Name tag of the EC2 instances created by an AutoScaling Group when used as a capacity provider for ECS.

Here is my code:

```
const cluster = new ecs.Cluster (
    this,
    "ECSCluster",
    {
        clusterName: "myCluster",
        vpc: my-vpc
    }
);

const autoScalingGroup = new autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup (
    this,
    "autoScalingGroup",
    {
        autoScalingGroupName: "myAutoScalingGroup",
        vpc: my-vpc,
        instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType("t3.2xlarge"),
        ... 
    }
);

const capacityProvider = new ecs.AsgCapacityProvider (
    this,
    "capacityProvider",
    { autoScalingGroup }
);

cluster.addAsgCapacityProvider(capacityProvider);
```

So this code works and it creates well my EC2 instances within an ECS cluster. The issue is I would like to change the Name tag which is a concatenation of the stack ID and the autoScalingGroup ID. So for me it's "ECSStack/autoScalingGroup".

How can I change the EC2 instances' Name tag?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Tags.of(myConstruct).add('key', 'value'); from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/tagging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found! Actually you don't have to retag the stack but autoScalingGroup instead. Here is the command based on the variables I have written above

```
Tags.of(autoScalingGroup).add("Name", "my-ecs")
```